# How to call procedure in php/mysqli?

Tags: php

i have using in MySQL. but i cant call the procedures.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "testDB");

$query = "SELECT * FROM testTable";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    header("Content-type: audio/mpeg"); 
    echo $row['audioData'];

    $result->free();
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: I don't see you call any procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php
//database gegevens
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "mysql";
$dbname = "db";


//maak connectie met database
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM testTable") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>=1) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $name = $row['name'];
   }   
  } 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the procedure using "CALL" keyword.

```
$query = "CALL procedure_name(para_1,para_2);";


$result = $mysqli->query($query)
```